# Moq Concrete Class with Internal Constructor

Tags: c#, moq, .net-assembly

I'm attempting to Moq a concrete class that has an internal constructor, i.e., in `MyAssembly` I have

```
public class MyClass {

    internal MyClass(){}

    // other methods including factory instance method
}
```

then in my test in `TestAssembly' I have

```
var mock = new Mock<MyClass>();
```

in `MyAssembly` I have added the following to `AssemblyInfo.cs`

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestAssembly")]
```

but even setting `TestAssembly` to be a friend of `MyAssembly`, Moq still throws the error

```
Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException
Can not instantiate proxy of class: Civica.Metadata.Models.Entities.Stage.
Could not find a parameterless constructor.
```

Should Moq be able to create mocks using internal constructors in this manner?

Comment: Moq wont be able to access the constructor to be able to mock the implementation.

Comment: @Nkosi Even when I've marked it as internals visible to? I can create an instance of my class using the internal constructor in my test project, so why can't Moq?

Comment: Looks like someone found an answer. Try it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Advanced Features section of the Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features).

> Mocking internal types of another project: add the following assembly
>   attribute (typically to the AssemblyInfo.cs) to the project containing
>   the internal types:

```
// This assembly is the default dynamic assembly generated Castle DynamicProxy, 
// used by Moq. Paste in a single line. 
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]
```

Comment: Good find. I totally missed that in the quick start

Comment: Thought this was working, but now get the error `System.MethodAccessException
Attempt by method 'Castle.Proxies.MyClassProxy..ctor(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[])' to access method 'MyAssembly.MyClass..ctor()' failed.
   at Castle.Proxies.StageProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[] )`

Comment: Using `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]` seems to work