# Moq access method failed for internal constructors

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've been attempting to use moq to mock a class with an internal constructor. Following on from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759384/moq-concrete-class-with-internal-constructor) i appear to be hitting the constructor, but now faced with a new error, i.e.,

> System.MethodAccessException
>       Attempt by method 'Castle.Proxies.MyClassProxy..ctor(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInterceptor[])'
>   to access method 'MyAssembly.MyClass..ctor()' failed.
>          at Castle.Proxies.StageProxy..ctor(IInterceptor[] )
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] >arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
>      at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
>      at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
>      at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
>      at Moq.Mock`1.b__20_0()
>      at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
>      at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
>      at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
>      at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
>      at TestAssembly.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in c:\users\briaris-j\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\TestMoqInternals\TestAssembly\UnitTest1.cs:line 16

This is my `AssemblyInfo.cs` for `MyAssembly`, i.e., the assembly containing my internal types

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyAssembly")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("MyAssembly")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2017")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("2fda4fb1-6855-4af5-a0a3-fbe861dcc734")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Allow moq to access internal constructors of entities
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]
```

Any ideas how this may be fixed?

Comment: Have you add the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute?

Comment: Yes, I have added: `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]` as per the [docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features)

Comment: Weird. Your error said that attempt to acces to the constructor failed so I think you didn't put the attribute to the correct assembly.

Comment: @CodeNotFound pretty sure i'm adding it in the right place - see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

So changing my `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute from

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]
```

to

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2"]
```

Seems to have done the trick. Weird the original was copied direct from the moq [docs](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#advanced-features)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the assembly where i added the [`assembly: InternalsVisibleTo` attribute, was also in the GAC so when running my unit test, it used the version in the GAC instead of the updated on where the attribute was added.
this caused the same error.